# getUserMedia volume changes, constraints not working

Tags: microphone, getusermedia

I can't stop my script from auto adjusting the microphone volume when recording via JS.

Windows 10, Chrome 59

I thought I could stop automatic volume control via the audio constraints, but it's not working.

```
        var constraints = {
            audio: {
                deviceId: 'default',
                echoCancellation: false,
                noiseSuppression: false,
                autoGainControl: false,
                googEchoCancellation: false,
                googEchoCancellation2: false,
                googAutoGainControl: false,
                googAutoGainControl2: false,
                googNoiseSuppression: false,
                googNoiseSuppression2: false,
                googDucking: false
            },
            video: false
        };
```

Here is my whole JSFiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/foyleman/hvkjzmre/

It's most apparent when testing with a standalone mic on the PC, setting the recording volume to 100. Then press Start to start the script and talk close and loud in your mic for about 30 seconds. Press stop and look at the system mic recording level... it went down.

Comment: `autoGainControl` and `noiseSuppression` got standardized [quite recently](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-of-the-week-audio-constraints/). Unless you use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), you may need to use the old `goog` and `moz` prefixed ones for a while longer.

Comment: adapter.js to the rescue. I think it's working.

Thanks @jibuse 

All of the direct markups as mentioned did not work. The addition of adapter.js and now it works.
<script src="//webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

Direct calls as I had originally done did not work. I thought I had them all covered.

The addition of adapter.js to the original script resolved the issue.

*note that I did not implement http(s) in the src because I wanted the script to work pretty much anywhere.

Thanks jib